# SVN: Attempt to add tree conflict that already exists / correct SVN workflow

Tags: svn, version-control, merge, tree-conflict

We have a branch created from trunk quite some time ago. I've merged the changes from trunk to this branch with:

```
svn merge url-of-trunk
```

This was painful, because in the meantime someone else applied changes from trunk to this branch, by copying them. But somehow I managed to do this.

Now I want to merge changes from this development branch back to trunk, but, what do you know, some changes from our branch were already applied to trunk. I get following error:

```
svn: Attempt to add tree conflict that already exists at 'filename.cpp'
svn: Error reading spooled REPORT request response
```

I tried to resolve this using svn resolve and svn resolved - these commands tell me that everything is now resolved, but re-running the merge gives me the same error on the same revision...

Is there a way to rescue this branch or should we create a new one? What do you think is the best way to merge changes back to trunk now?

And last question: if there will be a new branch, and on that branch we will merge changes from trunk daily, will this make merging back to trunk easy? (At least when no-one commits to same files in trunk?)

I had more luck with dealing with this by using svn command line for merging and tortoise for resolving conflicts. If you could suggest something that uses console commands only that would be great. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Marking it as "resolved" lets you commit your changes. You don't need to merge again.